# ERR_CONNECTION_REUSED using websocket on raspberry pi

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, raspberry-pi, java-websocket

I'm trying to create a simple webserver to control an LED via a Raspberry Pi. I can't get the browser to connect to the server.  I've read up on the CORS issues and have attempted to resolve by specifying the origin, but after a few hundred tried, I realize I need to help.

JS WEB SERVER:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http, {
  cors: {
    origin : "http://192.168.86.25:80",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders : ["my-custom-header"],
    credentials: true
    }
```

HTML CLIENT SIDE

```
var socket = io("http://192.168.86.25",{
  withCredentials : true,
  extraHeaders : {
    "my-custom-header" : "hello"
  }
});
```

http://192.168.86.25 is the IP address of the local Raspberry Pi.  The server starts up and the webpage loads at http://192.168.86.25:8080 but the websocket is not connecting.

I've tried changing the http://192.168.86.25 to:
http://localhost
http://localhost:8080
http://192.168.86.25:8080

In the network tab details, I see, code: 2, "Bad handshake method"

Setup:
Raspberry Pi 4 / Debian 10.7

[image: Error]

[image: Console Network Tab]

[image: Origin changed to http://192.168.86.25:8080]

Comment: Why is the origin in cors header `http://192.168.86.25:80` when the request is made from `http://192.168.86.25:8080`, Did you try using `*`? Also can you show the output from Network Tab.

Comment: I tried using :80 because I thought the browser itself defaults to using port 80.  I've also tried :8080 and specifying no port.  What I really don't understand is why there's any issue at all.  The web page and the web server are on the same machine, (the pi.)  I did also try using "*" but that's not allowed any longer.  The browser rejects it. THANKS FOR THE HELP!!!

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't actually know `*` [couldn't be used for requests with credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials), makes sense tho.

Comment: from my pov setting origin to `http://localhost:8080`  should then work (I didn't realize before you were making requests from localhost) I actually tried your code, and it works for me.

Comment: I'm getting a {"code" : 2, "message" : "Bad handshake method" on the POST

I upgraded to latest Node and NPM.  I'm getting a okay 200 on GET

This is with origin : "http://localhost:8080/" and "http://localhost:8080" and "localhost:8080"

Comment: I got it.  The HTML was referring to an old version of socket.io and the web server was using the new version installed via NPM.  Thanks for your help, your comments put me on the right track!